# Codeigniter - Issue getting value from mysql db

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I need your support because It's already one week that I'm not able to go further on developing my script.
Before to decide to develop my website in Codeigniter, I had developed a PHP script that took values from my mysql database. I'll fully report it here, so you can understand what I would like to reproduce also on Codeigniter.

My MySQL database has a row as the following:

```
Years | 2006 | 2007 | 2008 | 2009| 2010 | 2011 | 2012 | 2013 | 2014 | 2015
```

Years is the "**id**".

I named my table as

```
$table = $db_mysql_table;
```

So I wrote:

```
$y = "SELECT * FROM $table WHERE id = 'Years'";
$years = $mysqli->query($y);
```

So, I fetched the results using the following code:

```
$row_y = mysqli_fetch_array($years);

foreach($row_y as $key=>$value)
{
    if($row_y[$key]=="")
    {
        $row_y[$key]="-";
    }
}

echo '<tr>';
echo '<th></th>';
for ($i = 1, $k=11; $i < $k; $i++) {
    echo '<th><strong>';
    echo substr($row_y[$i], 0, -3);
    echo '</strong></th>';
}
echo '<th><strong>TTM</strong></th>';
echo '</tr>';

mysqli_free_result($years);
```

What I tried to do in CodeIgniter is the following:

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->where('id', 'Years');
$years = $this->db->get($table);

$row_y = mysqli_fetch_array($years);

foreach($row_y as $key=>$value)
{
    if($row_y[$key]=="")
    {
        $row_y[$key]="-";
    }
}

echo '<tr>';
echo '<th></th>';
for ($i = 1, $k=11; $i < $k; $i++) {
    echo '<th><strong>';
    echo substr($row_y[$i], 0, -3);
    echo '</strong></th>';
}
echo '<th><strong>TTM</strong></th>';
echo '</tr>';

mysqli_free_result($years);
```

What am I doing wrong? I don't understand...maybe for me it's still not so clear the MySQL DB logic of CodeIgniter. Could you please support me?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: you don't call mysqli functions on CI db objects...RTFM? https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/results.html

Comment: First familiarize on the Model / View / Approach of CI. Check the manual it's all there. https://codeigniter.com/docs

Comment: @MarcB thanks for your link, I'm taking a look on it :)

@ reignsly: That's clear! I already know very well the MVA approach of CI...it's just a DB issue. Thanks for your reply.